# Android Dagger 2.11 cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, exception, dagger-2

In my project, I use the **Salut** library to use the wi-fi direct. Below is the class constructor:

```
public Salut(SalutDataReceiver dataReceiver, 
             SalutServiceData salutServiceData, 
             SalutCallback deviceNotSupported) {
...
}
```

Class SalutDataReceiver as parameters takes a reference to activity. He also takes a callback. Below is the class constructor:

```
public SalutDataReceiver(Activity activity, SalutDataCallback dataCallback) {
}
```

Since there is a rigid link with activity, I assume that this object should be transferred from the outside. Below is the class of the module and component:

```
@Module
public class WifiCommunicationModule {

    public WifiCommunicationModule() {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Salut provideSalut(SalutDataReceiver dataReceiver) {
        SalutServiceData serviceData = new SalutServiceData("testService", 50489, "test");
        return new Salut(dataReceiver, serviceData, null);
    }
}


 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = {
            AppModule.class,
            WifiCommunicationModule.class
    })
    public interface MainComponent {
        void inject(MainActivity activity);
    }


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Salut salut;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

**But at compilation throws an exception:**

> Error:(25, 10) error: com.peak.salut.SalutDataReceiver cannot be
>   provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated
>   method. com.peak.salut.SalutDataReceiver is injected at
>   com.test.modules.WifiCommunicationModule.provideSalut(dataReceiver)
>   com.peak.salut.Salut is injected at
>   com.test.views.activities.MainActivity.salut
>   com.test.views.activities.MainActivity is injected at
>   com.test.components.MainComponent.inject(activity)

**UPDATE**

Mr. @Zayniddin Mamarasulov recommended that you create a derived class from the SalutDataReceiver and mark the constructor as @Inject. But unfortunately this also does not work

```
public class SalutDataReceiverExtension extends SalutDataReceiver {

    @Inject
    public SalutDataReceiverExtension(Activity activity, SalutDataCallback dataCallback) {
        super(activity, dataCallback);
    }
}


@Module
public class WifiCommunicationModule {

    public WifiCommunicationModule() {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Salut provideSalut(SalutDataReceiverExtension dataReceiver) {
        SalutServiceData serviceData = new SalutServiceData("testService", 50489, "test");
        return new Salut(dataReceiver, serviceData, null);
    }
}
```

> Error:(25, 10) error: android.app.Activity cannot be provided without
>   an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
>   android.app.Activity is injected at
>   com.test.implementation.SalutDataReceiverExtend.(activity, …)
>   com.test.implementation.SalutDataReceiverExtend is injected at
>   com.test.modules.WifiCommunicationModule.provideSalut(dataReceiver)
>   com.peak.salut.Salut is injected at
>   com.test.views.activities.MainActivity.salut
>   com.test.views.activities.MainActivity is injected at
>   com.test.components.MainComponent.inject(activity)

Answer (score 0):

Add @Inject annotation to SalutDataReceiver's constructor like this :

```
@Inject
public SalutDataReceiver(Activity activity, SalutDataCallback dataCallback) {
}
```

Comment: This is an external library, I can not do this

Comment: did you try to override its constructor ?

Comment: try to extend SalutDataReceiver class and add @Inject annotation to your own class's constructor. I can't say exactly that it works , but it may help you